# htaccess password protection not working

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have been trying to password protect a directory on my server and I can get it to work with just using a user but when I add a password it does not work.

In my .htpasswd file:

Working -> admin:

Not Working -> admin:password

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Password Generator" -> http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Example:

Win:

```
admin:password <- Normal
```

Linux:

```
admin:$apr1$6XdDuZmL$Nx.TRhnKGYkbvl2pY0Pgb/
```